# Getting Offline HTTPesponse for UWP app

Tags: uwp, c++-cx, cpprest-sdk

I am working on Universal Windows Platform app. As a client this app needs WebServices to be called. Hence i have added C++ REST SDK in my project. I am able to call the HTTP Request and i am getting the response as well. 
As i disconnect from the internet i am expecting no response. but still i am getting the response on offline as well. I am using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. This project is in C++/CX.
Below is my code:

```
void PrintResponse(http_response response)
{
// Display the status code that the server returned
std::wostringstream stream;

auto bodyStream = response.body();
streams::stringstreambuf sbuffer;
auto& target = sbuffer.collection();

bodyStream.read_to_end(sbuffer).get();

OutputDebugStringA(target.c_str()); 
}

pplx::task<void> HTTPGetAsync()
{
http_client client(U("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors"));
// Make an HTTP GET request and asynchronously process the response
return client.request(methods::GET).then([](http_response response)
{
    PrintResponse(response);
});
}


MainPage::MainPage(){
InitializeComponent();
StudentListView->ItemsSource = Student::CreateStudent();

HTTPGetAsync();
}
```

Please help me for this, so that i wont get offline response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this C++/CX or C++/WinRT? Please update your tags appropriately.

Comment: I'm not sure which wrapper library you're using for the http_client type, but in your request call, try setting the Cache-Control header to no-cache.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control